# Share Table between two or more models WITHOUT relationship - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am not yet able to find any relevant answers on Stack Overflow. I have to share one database table between two models. Below are the details:

```
[Table("OBS_Pre-Post_Checks")]
public class OBSPrePostChecks
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Row_Identifier { get; set; }
    public string RequestID { get; set; }
    public string SiteID { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public string PriRouter { get; set; }
    public string PriRouterIP { get; set; }
    public string SecRouter { get; set; }
    public string SecRouterIP { get; set; }
    public string RouterConnect { get; set; }
    public string RouterAppType { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Prechecktime { get; set; }
    public string PrecheckOutput { get; set; }
    public string Precheckflow { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Postchecktime { get; set; }
    public string PostcheckOutput { get; set; }
    public string Postcheckflow { get; set; }
    public string TicketNumber { get; set; }
    public string ExecutedBy { get; set; }
}

[Table("OBS_Pre-Post_Checks")]
public class OBSPrePostChecksSubSet
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Row_Identifier { get; set; }
    public string RequestID { get; set; }
    public string SiteID { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public string PriRouter { get; set; }
    public string PriRouterIP { get; set; }
    public string SecRouter { get; set; }
    public string SecRouterIP { get; set; }
    public string RouterConnect { get; set; }
    public string RouterAppType { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Prechecktime { get; set; }
    public string Precheckflow { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Postchecktime { get; set; }
    public string Postcheckflow { get; set; }
    public string TicketNumber { get; set; }
    public string ExecutedBy { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see in the second table, I am excluding two properties `PrecheckOutput` and `PostcheckOutput` from the table since those two columns are very huge `(nvarchar(MAX))` and are required on demand. It takes 5+ minutes if we don't exclude those columns.

I have to first load the `OBSPrePostChecksSubSet`, as a dashboard table and when a user clicks on a row it will load the details for that particular row using the `Row_Identifier` by making another call to the DB.

This approach is significantly reducing the initial load time for the Dashboard table.

However, I am getting below Error:

> The entity types 'OBSPrePostChecksSubSet' and 'OBSPrePostChecks'
> cannot share table 'OBS_Pre-Post_Checks' because they are not in the
> same type hierarchy or do not have a valid one to one foreign key
> relationship with matching primary keys between them.

**EDIT**: Adding the code for Controller Functions that I tried to use.

This is the code in Controller:

```
    // Function to get OBS Pre-Post Check History
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult OBSLoadPrePostCheckHistory()
    {
        List<OBSPrePostChecksSubSet> PrePostCheckHistoryTable = new List<OBSPrePostChecksSubSet>();
        try
        {
            using (NetworkAutomationContext NAC = new NetworkAutomationContext())
            {
                PrePostCheckHistoryTable = NAC.OBSPrePostChecksSubSets.AsNoTracking().ToList();

                if (PrePostCheckHistoryTable == null || PrePostCheckHistoryTable?.Count == 0)
                {
                    PrePostCheckHistoryTable.Add(new OBSPrePostChecksSubSet
                    {
                        Row_Identifier = Guid.Empty,
                        RequestID = "NA",
                        SiteID = "NA",
                        PriRouter = "No records found",
                        PriRouterIP = "NA",
                        SecRouter = "No records found",
                        SecRouterIP = "NA",
                        RouterConnect = "NA",
                        RouterAppType = "NA",
                        Prechecktime = DateTime.MinValue,
                        Precheckflow = "NA",
                        Postchecktime = DateTime.MinValue,
                        Postcheckflow = "NA",
                        TicketNumber = "NA",
                        ExecutedBy = "NA"
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string Error = ex.Message;
            Error = Error.Contains("inner exception") ? ex.InnerException.Message : Error;
            Error = Error.Contains("inner exception") ? ex.InnerException.InnerException.Message : Error;

            PrePostCheckHistoryTable.Add(new OBSPrePostChecksSubSet
            {
                Row_Identifier = Guid.Empty,
                RequestID = "Error",
                SiteID = "Error",
                PriRouter = $"{Error}",
                PriRouterIP = "Error",
                SecRouter = "Error",
                SecRouterIP = "Error",
                RouterConnect = "Error",
                RouterAppType = "Error",
                Prechecktime = DateTime.MinValue,
                Precheckflow = "Error",
                Postchecktime = DateTime.MinValue,
                Postcheckflow = "Error",
                TicketNumber = "Error",
                ExecutedBy = "Error"
            });
        }
        return Json(PrePostCheckHistoryTable, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    // Function to get Single row details for Pre-Post Check History
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult OBSLoadPrePostCheckRow(string RowIdentifier)
    {
        OBSPrePostChecks PrePostCheckHistoryRow = null;
        Guid RowID = Guid.Parse(RowIdentifier);
        try
        {
            using (NetworkAutomationContext NAC = new NetworkAutomationContext())
            {
                PrePostCheckHistoryRow = NAC.OBSPrePostCheckss.Where(row => row.Row_Identifier == RowID).FirstOrDefault();

                if (PrePostCheckHistoryRow == null)
                {
                    PrePostCheckHistoryRow = new OBSPrePostChecks
                    {
                        Row_Identifier = Guid.Empty,
                        RequestID = "NA",
                        SiteID = "NA",
                        PriRouter = "No records found",
                        PriRouterIP = "NA",
                        SecRouter = "No records found",
                        SecRouterIP = "NA",
                        RouterConnect = "NA",
                        RouterAppType = "NA",
                        Prechecktime = DateTime.MinValue,
                        PostcheckOutput = "Error",
                        PrecheckOutput = "Error",
                        Precheckflow = "NA",
                        Postchecktime = DateTime.MinValue,
                        Postcheckflow = "NA",
                        TicketNumber = "NA",
                        ExecutedBy = "NA"
                    };
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string Error = ex.Message;
            Error = Error.Contains("inner exception") ? ex.InnerException.Message : Error;
            Error = Error.Contains("inner exception") ? ex.InnerException.InnerException.Message : Error;

            PrePostCheckHistoryRow = new OBSPrePostChecks
            {
                Row_Identifier = Guid.Empty,
                RequestID = "Error",
                SiteID = "Error",
                PriRouter = $"{Error}",
                PriRouterIP = "Error",
                SecRouter = "Error",
                SecRouterIP = "Error",
                RouterConnect = "Error",
                RouterAppType = "Error",
                Prechecktime = DateTime.MinValue,
                PostcheckOutput = "Error",
                PrecheckOutput = "Error",
                Precheckflow = "Error",
                Postchecktime = DateTime.MinValue,
                Postcheckflow = "Error",
                TicketNumber = "Error",
                ExecutedBy = "Error"
            };
        }
        return Json(PrePostCheckHistoryRow, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: You can create 1-1 relationship between OBS_Pre-Post_Check and a new table which contains only big strings.

Comment: That will need lot of changes in the framework, since the data is feed by some other tools (like SCORCH flows and python scripts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1: Adjust the schema to move the "heavy" columns to a 1-to-1 table /w PK. Create a HasOne-WithOne relationship between the PrePostCheck and PrePostCheckOutputs entities.

If you cannot adjust the schema...

Option 2: Bounded DbContexts - Use a separate DbContext for dealing with either the detailed PrePostCheck or the summary one. Your main application DbContext can be configured for the summary definition excluding these strings, then hand off to a different DbContext to retrieve the complete details.

Option 3: Projection - Instead of returning entities, project the details you need to display into a view model. For example:

```
var details = context.PrePostChecks
    .Where(x => /* enter criteria */ )
    .Select(x => new PrePostCheckSummary
    {
        Row_Identifier = x.Row_Identifier,
        RequestID = x.RequestID,
        // ... add values view will need...
        // exclude the expensive fields.
    }).ToList();
```

Leveraging AutoMapper you can define the Entity to ViewModel mapping configuration then instead call:

```
var details = context.PrePostChecks
    .Where(x => /* enter criteria */ )
    .ProjectTo<PrePostCheckSummary>(mapperConfig)
    .ToList();
```

I recommend option 3 for any data going to a view to generally avoid passing any data the view doesn't need as well as avoiding things like lazy loading serialization traps.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. If I plan to go with Option 3, I don't have anything to put in `.Where(x => /* enter criteria */ )`, I guess it will still be slow as it will first try to load everything then it will perform `.Select(x => new PrePostCheckSummary...`

Comment: I went with Option 2. It is working for me now. BTW< I would still like to know about Option 3 it may be useful in some other case.